# CollectionView with height equal to max height of CustomCell in Swift

Tags: ios, dynamic, height, collectionview

I am trying to have collection view(horizontal/vertical) with some height. Inside this, I have custom cells with many subviews(ex:image, title, description, last updated etc. ).

Now I want all cells to maintain same height which is the max height of all cells(based on data). **(Each Cell height = Cell with max height)**

I am able to create dynamic height cell but could not understand where to put the max height logic.

Currently I have following code

**ViewController**

```
lazy var flowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal // .vertical
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10

    return layout
}()

lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)
    cv.backgroundColor = .white

    return cv
}()

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let targetWidth = collectionView.bounds
        .inset(collectionView.contentInset)
        .inset(flowLayout.sectionInset)
        .width

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! SampleCell
    cell.configure(data: randomTexts[indexPath.row])

    let size = cell.systemLayoutSizeFitting(
        .init(width: targetWidth, height: 0),
        withHorizontalFittingPriority: .required, verticalFittingPriority: .fittingSizeLevel)

    return size
}
```

**SampleCell : UICollectionViewCell**

```
override func systemLayoutSizeFitting( _ targetSize: CGSize, withHorizontalFittingPriority horizontalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority,
                                       verticalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority) -> CGSize {

    let contentSize = contentView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(
        targetSize,
        withHorizontalFittingPriority: horizontalFittingPriority,
        verticalFittingPriority: verticalFittingPriority)

    return contentSize.withWidth(targetSize.width)
}
```

**Extensions**

```
extension CGRect {
func inset(_ insets: UIEdgeInsets) -> CGRect {
    return self.inset(by: insets)
}}
```

Where will max height logic goes: ViewController or SampleCell and how to achieve the same?

Note: Also looking on how to do this for horizontal/vertical scrolling( collection with some height(and adjust a/c to the cell content) inside a viewcontroller)

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:)` method, return the max height here.

Comment: But in collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:)  we have init(width: targetWidth, height: 0) which has no height but it's calculated inside cell(I think). So my question is how does it work if I put it  in sizeForItemAt. 
Could you provide some snippet for the logic. I am really stuck with this approach.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are referring to. Have you got a way to calculate the maxCellHeight ? As per my understanding, the ``` collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:) ``` is called before the cell is being added in collectionView. So, if at that time, you pass that height it should render that appropriately

Comment: I guess in collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:), height is calculated for each cell based on it's data but let's say last item has more height than all cells height then all cells should resize their height to this last cell's height which is maximum.

Comment: in my opinion you're gonna have to calculate it beforehand as per the content size of individual items. I'd try to create an example to check otherwise and get back to you if I get something